# Cassandra sstablesplit throws error "Unknown Keyspace" while splitting SSTable file

Tags: cassandra

Executing ssablesplit command as below is throwing below error:

```
root@cas-sleep-pod:/data/cassandra/public# /opt/cassandra/tools/bin/sstablesplit -s 30720 --no-snapshot /data/cassandra/public/timebucket_auditlog_primary-b275e92070a511eda32ced63d2298aec/me-1172-big-Data.db
WARN  12:43:44,036 Only 14.359GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Unknown keyspace public
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.<init>(Keyspace.java:316)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.open(Keyspace.java:129)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.openWithoutSSTables(Keyspace.java:112)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.StandaloneSplitter.main(StandaloneSplitter.java:114)
```

I'm actually executing this command after stopping cassandra pod and mounting the hostPath of the cassandra "data" directory into another pod. (has same cassandra image)

```
root@cas-sleep-pod:/data/cassandra/public# ls -ld timebucket_auditlog_primary-b275e92070a511eda32ced63d2298aec/
drwxr-xr-x 3 cassandra cassandra 16384 Aug 23 07:47 timebucket_auditlog_primary-b275e92070a511eda32ced63d2298aec/
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption here is that your cassandra.yaml data directory setting is probably `/data/cassandra/<keyspace>/<table>` and so *sstablesplit* is looking for that path and not what you currently have with the `public` directory in there. You should be able to either mimic the same path or modify the cassandra.yaml data_directory path (without a restart so that it never actually takes effect) to what you're using for the *sstablesplit* command. I think that should work for you.